# Use table prefix after installation

Tags: database, mysql, table

I finally have been able to install Craft CMS. During installation I left the table prefix field empty. I assume that for each site separate tables are created. Therefore, it would be more user-friendly to use a different table prefix for each site. How can I add a table prefix after the installation?

Is it sufficient to rename each table manually and then add the prefix to the .env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only need to add a prefix if you were planning on multiple installs of Craft on the same DB, most likely you are not so you can just leave it blank.

You don't need seperate DBs for a multi-site install.

If you did install with different DB prefixes for each, each Craft install would need to be licensed seperately; again probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: 100% agree with Seth. Worth mentioning if you're on a recent version of Craft, there is a `php craft db/drop-table-prefix` CLI command, which goes the other direction. i.e. remove table prefixes if you're using them.